# Git ignore does not work with some extensions

Tags: git, gitignore

`.gitignore` contains the only line `*.out`
However, on some PC `git status` shows files with `.out` extensions

How to fix this ?

**Update** - the `.out` files are not tracked !

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your repository already contains the particular file being shown in `git status`'s output. Is that the case? If so, it's working as designed, and there are other questions that already have good answers explaining why it works like that. I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Actually, *.out are not tracked. I they were, I'd solved the problem some hours ago

Comment: ' on some PC' -> so what is different on that pc?  what does git version show?  have you double checked .gitignore on that pc including checking for file perms, invisible chars etc?

Comment: `.out` is visible under git version `1.9.5.msysgit.0`  and invisible under  `1.9.4.msysgit.0`

Comment: Perhaps you have different commits checked out in the two locations, and the contents of `.gitignore` is different in one of them? Or maybe a `.gitignore` in a subdirectory overrides the one in the root of the working directory? Posting actual output might help sort that out...

Comment: Please show the output of `git status` and `cat .gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

The gitignore file ignores only files which aren't already added to the repo so non tracked files. You have to remove them first with:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Otherwise the files are modified when you edit them.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` works only for non tracked files so other users should remove them from index.

Answer (score 0):

gitignore rules must be alone on their line in order to work. That is:

```
*.out  # My output logs
```

will not work; while:

```
# My output logs
*.out
```

will work. I'm guessing that this is because gitignore looks for comments as lines that start with `#`